# My laptop Latitude E7470 core i5 sometimes shows images pixelated

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, dell-latitude

I have an issue with my laptop but I don't know if it is software issue or hardware. The issue is that sometimes the images shows pixelated sometimes it is ok. I will attach screenshot for more clarification.

apologize if my question is not very clear but I will try to include all the details.
[image: here is the screenshot]

Comment: What happens if you scroll the pixelated content (or move the window it’s in)? What about moving another window on top? Have you tried 3D software yet? Perhaps try viewing [this WebGL sample](https://webglsamples.org/blob/blob.html) in various browsers.

Comment: thanks for your replay. when i move the pixelated content then those pixels also change places and sometime it reduce the pixels and sometime the image looks ok all the pixel colors go away

Answer (score 1):

> I have an issue with my laptop but I don't know if it is software
> issue or hardware. The issue is that sometimes the images shows pixelated sometimes it is ok

**First:**

Use the Dell Driver Update App and update all Drivers including BIOS (UEFI), Chipset, and Video for certain and all other drivers.

After the restart that occurs, update Windows fully .  Check in Optional Windows Updates and do those as well.

**Second:**

If you still have issues, Use the Dell Hardware Diagnostics App and test all hardware.

If there is a hardware issue, you may need to have the machine serviced.

Comment: thanks for your answer I will try the first option for second option I have tried but the SupportAssest app shows error while installing which i have searched online and didn't work.

Comment: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ozqlH2V)

Comment: Dell may also have a separate driver update app - try that. Also look on their support site for BIOS, Chipset and Video driver updates and do them manually.